# Как получить context в onMessageReceived?

Tags: android, firebase-android, context

Есть метод который находит имя контакта по номеру и он работает нормально в `activity`.

Необходимо, чтобы он работал в сервисе `FirebaseMessagingService()` в методе `onMessageReceived()`, когда приложение в фоне и когда не запущен.

Для этого необходимо `context` приложение, так вот, как его получить? или как правильно это реализовать?

Answer (score -2):

Просто используйте this в вашем сервисе что наследует FirebaseMessagingService